Issue with tables
I am currently writing my thesis, and, as expected, MS Word has caused several issues. The main problem I’m encountering is related to tables. The issues I’m facing include text in some cells overflowing beyond the text area due to its length, and tables that are too long and need to extend to the next page.
Here are my questions:

How can I force the table to stay within the limits of the text area?
How can I define the column width and ensure that the text is left-aligned, for instance? To make things simpler, is it possible to define the width of the first column and have the remaining columns equally distributed across the page's text area?
How can I make the text wrap without hyphenation?
If the table needs to extend to the next page, is there a way for this to happen automatically depending on the included text?

\begin{table}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllll} \toprule
             & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Multicolumn heading} \\ \cmidrule{2-5}
        Heading for column 1 & Column 2 heading & Column 3 heading & Column 4 heading & Column 5 heading \\ \midrule
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
        Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Edit: Page size is A4. Top, bottom, left, right margins are 1inch.
I would really appreciate your help!
Thank you in advance
Best regards,
A.

Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

And please note, we currently don't know the limits of you text area. because you've shown only a code snippet. So please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Currently I would guess, that breaking the column heads could help to fit the table. This could be done, e.g., using package multirow, using an internal tabular, using a \parbox etc.

@cabohah Thank you for your comment. However, I’m not very sure what you mean. I included all the questions in the same thread since they refer to the same table and to avoid spamming. Perhaps I haven't understood something correctly.

Generally using p{…} columns or tabularx could also help to allow line breaks in cells.

Wrapping without hyphenation is independent from tabulars supported using \raggedright or package ragged2e. But there are also already tabular specific questions about it → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52246/277964

How to allow page-breaks inside a tabular is also more or less independent from your other questions. And there are already questions about it → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26462/277964

@cabohah I am still trying to figure out which template I should use. Thank you for pointing me to these solutions. Obviously, I lack the knowledge, so I can't determine which ones are relevant or not. I have tried some of the solutions you proposed; however, I still can't make it work.

See my second comment and the link in it.

I think all of your stated typesetting objectives, formulated as questions, are fine except for #3, suppressing hyphenation. The narrower the columns, the more important it is to allow hyphenation in order to keep lines of text from becoming excessively ragged.
It sounds like your table could benefit from being set up as an xltabular environment, which combines the capabilities of the longtable (span more than one page, if needed) and the tabularx environments (set target widths, allow text wrapping).
The following code shows how this may be done, using your code snippet as a starting point.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % suppress full justification

\begin{document} 

% Set target widths for the overall table (here: \textwidth) 
% and for the first column (here: 4cm). Widths of remaining
% four columns are determined as a residual.

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} P{4cm} LLLL @{}}

    %% specify headers and footers
    
    \caption{Test} \label{tab:my_label} \\
    \toprule
    Column 1 heading & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Multicolumn heading} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Column 2 heading & Column 3 heading & Column 4 heading & Column 5 heading \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    Column 1 heading & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Multicolumn heading} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Column 2 heading & Column 3 heading & Column 4 heading & Column 5 heading \\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    
    %% body of table
    
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 

    
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}


Addendum to incorporate the additional information the OP has provided in the comments: I'm afraid I am unable to reproduce the messages the OP reports getting if I replace
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

with
\documentclass[11pt,paper=b5,footinclude,headinclude]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

and change the width of the first column from 4cm to 3cm. Indeed, the first few lines of the resulting table look like this:

%% new information provided by the OP :
\documentclass[11pt,paper=b5,footinclude,headinclude]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{classicthesis}

%% be sure to copy the next 3 lines of code into your document
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % suppress full justification

\begin{document} 

% Set target widths for the overall table (here: \textwidth) 
% and for the first column (here: 3cm). Widths of remaining
% four columns are determined as a residual.

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} P{3cm} LLLL @{}}

    %% specify headers and footers
    
    \caption{Test} \label{tab:my_label} \\
    \toprule
    Column 1 heading & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Multicolumn heading} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Column 2 heading & Column 3 heading & Column 4 heading & Column 5 heading \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    Column 1 heading & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Multicolumn heading} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & Column 2 heading & Column 3 heading & Column 4 heading & Column 5 heading \\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    
    %% body of table
    
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\     
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\
    Test & Test & Test & Test & Test \\ 
    
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}


Thank you a lot! This is extremely helpful! I will test it and come back to you

I am using the classicthesis template for my thesis. I used the code you provided, and the table text overflowed beyond the text area. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you! I get the following error message:
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (P): c' used. Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (2cm): c' used.
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (L): `c' used.
Overfull \hbox (172.26018pt too wide) in alignment at lines 95--95

@meletkis - "I am using the classicthesis template for my thesis." Please be more specific. E.g., what's the underlying document class?

I hope this is what you are referring to: \documentclass[11pt,paper=b5,footinclude,headinclude]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book - I tried changing that to a4, but no luck

@meletkis - I've posted an addendum to show the table that results from changing the \documentclass directive and from loading the classicthesis package. I'm afraid I am unable to reproduce any of the error and warning messages you say you're getting. I suspect you have failed to copy over the preamble of my answer document into your document.

For sure I am doing something wrong. Will re-run everything by re-installing the template. Thank you once more!
